# grub pc cannot be installed

Tags: system-installation

I want to install elementary OS within VMware Workstation Pro 12. I have configured the elementary disk to be on a usb my passport drive. At the end of the installation I get the error: grub pc cannot be installed. My host OS is Windows 8.1

Thanks for support

Comment: I am facing the same problem installation throwing me that error both in legacy and uefi mode and I already have windows 8.1 installed in legacy mode , I read somewhere that installing while not connected to internet throws you that error ,so what's your case ? where you installing without being connected internet because I want to give it a shot but I have a very slow internet .

Answer (score 0):

OK I tried with internet connection and the grub installed properly without any error :-)